# CSS hexagonal li, how?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a navigation menu with 'li'-s.
I want to make this li to hexagonal like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: please add more context to your question, are the menu items displayed over a plain colour or over an image/gradient? Adding an example code of what you have tried is also a plus and your question would be better accepted by the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a pseudo-element with borders.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    font-size; 64px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding:.5em 2em 0;
    margin: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    width: calc(100% - 1em); /* twice border width */
    border:.5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color:black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Longer Text</li>
    <li>Really Long Text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I, like @Paulie_D, would use pseudo elements for this, but I would create it in a slightly different way, (using skews):

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;padding:0;
  background:url(http://www.lorempixel.com/900/900);
  }
li {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:top;
}
li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10px;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  background: inherit;
}
li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10px;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Really Long Text which spans multiple lines</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would use a single pseudo with perspective transform :D